# IOS Twitter sdk Error

Tags: ios, twitter, sdk

Hi i have just added an app to twitter developer.
I have added **"Consumer Key"** & **"Consumer Secret"** to IOS app.

I have been using parse framework to link PFUser account to twitter.

Refer below code :-

```
- (IBAction)actionLinkTwitter:(UIButton *)sender
{
if (!sender.selected) { // not linked, link it!
    [PFTwitterUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"User linked their Twitter account!");
            sender.selected = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        }
    }];
} else { // linked, unlink it!
    [PFTwitterUtils unlinkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"The user is no longer associated with their Twitter account.");
            sender.selected = NO;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
        }
    }];
}
```

}

but every time an error is occurring.
refer below details for error :-

**Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7b6c8160 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x7c025a60 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the real twitter username in iOS 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154184/get-the-real-twitter-username-in-ios-6)

Comment: use social and accounts frame work for thsi

Comment: Can you elaborate a little? or give me a link from where i can refer.?

Comment: see my updated question.

Comment: oh oh are you using parse

Comment: yes i tried googled it but can not find much about this error.